# Why does typing a division expression into Chrome omnibar try to load an IP address?

Tags: google-chrome

I usually type math expressions into the Chrome omnibar to get some quick results. However typing `1000/4/30` attempts to load `http://0.0.3.232/4/30`. Why is that?

I can remedy it by appending `?` to the expression (i.e `?1000/4/30`).

Comment: This was written about on the [SU blog](http://blog.superuser.com/2012/10/15/increase-your-ping-fu/), see [LarsH's](http://superuser.com/a/486904/68111) or [Synetech's answer](http://superuser.com/questions/486788/why-does-pinging-192-168-072-only-2-dots-return-a-response-from-192-168-0-58/486936#486936).

Comment: See also [WTFriday: http://2915189091](http://blog.superuser.com/2012/02/10/wtfriday-http2915189091/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chrome is interpreting `1000/4/30` as an IP address and a path to a resource.  Here is the translation:

```
1000d = 1111101000b
```

So if you take that binary number and iterpret it as an IP address it becomes

```
00000000.00000000.00000011.11101000 = 0.0.3.232
```

And so Chrome thinks you're trying to access the host at the IP `0.0.3.232` and accessing the resource at path `/4/30`