# Why can I ping 127.1?

Tags: ip-address, specifications, ipv4

I know IPv6 allows consecutive zeros to be omitted. But how about IPv4? I haven't found any reference to this on the Internet, including Wikipedia and [RFC 791](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc791) – Internet Protocol. [This document](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=/rzai2/rzai2compipv4ipv6.htm)  suggests that "Leading zeros can be omitted" in an IPv4 address (search for the term 'omitted'). Not specific enough.

Check out this shell session:

```
[~]$ ping -c 1 127.1
PING 127.1 (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.040 ms

--- 127.1 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.040/0.040/0.040/0.000 ms
[~]$ ping -c 1 127.0.1
PING 127.0.1 (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.044 ms

--- 127.0.1 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.044/0.044/0.044/0.000 ms
[~]$ ssh 127.1 :
The authenticity of host '127.1 (127.0.0.1)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is 04:48:fa:f2:ef:95:7c:35:46:39:2e:d3:89:dd:cd:87.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added '127.1' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
alex@127.1's password:
```

**Clearly, both ping and ssh understand 127.1 and 127.0.1 to be the same as 127.0.0.1. Where is this specified?**

Comment: [This man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/inet_aton) linked in [this Stack Overflow post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10133820/is-there-any-documentation-for-ommiting-zeroes-in-dot-decimal-notation-of-ipv4-a) may be right up your alley.

Comment: That's an ancient notation style, but yes: it does work :-)

Comment: @nerdwaller: Please post that as an answer. (Bonus points if you figure out why `ping 0.0.0.0` or `ping 0` works the same way...)

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/486788/why-does-pinging-192-168-072-only-2-dots-return-a-response-from-192-168-0-58

Answer (score 17):

There's a Stack Overflow post from about a year ago asking something similar ([this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10133820/is-there-any-documentation-for-ommiting-zeroes-in-dot-decimal-notation-of-ipv4-a)).

The main reason is how `inet_aton()` ([man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/inet_aton)) converts the octets into the binary address.

> a.b.c.d
>
> Each of the four numeric parts specifies a byte of the address; the
>   bytes are assigned in left-to-right order to produce the binary
>   address.
>
> a.b.c
>
> Parts a and b specify the first two bytes of the binary address. Part
>   c is interpreted as a 16-bit value that defines the rightmost two
>   bytes of the binary address. This notation is suitable for specifying
>   (outmoded) Class B network addresses.
>
> a.b
>
> Part a specifies the first byte of the binary address. Part b is
>   interpreted as a 24-bit value that defines the rightmost three bytes
>   of the binary address. This notation is suitable for specifying
>   (outmoded) Class C network addresses.
>
> a
>
> The value a is interpreted as a 32-bit value that is stored directly into the binary address without any byte rearrangement.

**This isn't defined by POSIX.anything - but it is available pretty widely.**

Comment: Awesome, and I also checked the post you linked to on Stack Overflow. It had great insights on how different number systems can be used.  @grawity [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Protocol_version_4#Special-use_addresses) says 0.0.0.0/8 is the current network. I assume 0.0.0.0/32 must be the current host and that ping only expects /32 "networks". I have not found an explicit reference though.

Comment: @AlexandredeVerteuil: ping expects *hosts*, not networks... so yes, /32 for IPv4.

Answer (score 4):

It's a relic from the old days of classful addressing. `127.1` means network `127`, host `1`. (And, yes, `127.257` is legal because network `127` can have more than 256 hosts.

Comment: 127.257 meaning in particular 127.0.1.1, an address I actually see on old KMS server activator that worked on Windows 8.0